# Cannot add new correlated record to new created record

Tags: google-app-maker

When I create new record in Google AppMaker and then try to add correlated record to this new one I get this warning in console:

> com.google.apps.appmaker.client.datasource.AbstractModelDataSource
>   WARNING: Could not find element with key RecordKey{key=private$7,
>   model key=...

Both datasources are set to:

```
Manual save mode 
Automatically load data
```

The problem doesn't appear when I refresh the page or try to add correlated record to other existing record.

Anybody knows what could be a reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

App Maker doesn't allow to have unsaved changes on both ends of relation, most likely it is a reason, why you recieve error message in the first case. But in theory it should work once you save one of the relation ends (first save one of the records and then link them and save again):

```js
var countryDs = app.datasources.Country;
var capitalDs = app.datasources.Capital;

countryDs.createItem();
countryDs.item.Name = 'United States';

countryDs.saveChanges(function() {
  capitalDs.createItem();
  capitalDs.item.Name = 'Washington, D.C.';
  capitalDs.item.Country = countryDs.item;

  capitalDs.saveChanges();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it.
I have two forms. First to create item. Second to edit data. In the first form page need to be set to:

```
On Detach: Clear Changes To Datasource.
```

Datasources need to be set to **autosave.**